# Error while uploading tar.gz file through uri module using rest api

Tags: ansible

I written below code to upload the tar.gz file through rest api using ansible uri module

```
- name: Upload tar.gz file
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
       - name: Upload tar.gz file
         uri:
           url: "<url>/upload_tar_gz"
           method: POST
           HEADER_Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"
           force_basic_auth: yes
           user: "{{username}}"
           password: "{{password}}"
           status_code: 200
           validate_certs: no
           return_content: yes
           body_format: json
           body: "{{ lookup('file','test_file.tar.gz') }}"
```

But getting an below error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a , original message: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte"}

Looks like file plugin unable to load tar.gz file. Any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lookups will never be able to handle binary data due to being implemented via jinja2.

Refer below ansible github link
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11594